# URISyntax exception while exporting to word doc in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jboss5.x

I am getting the following error when I use *JasperReports 3.7.6* to export report to the word document.

It works fine with *JR 3.6.0* and *4.0.0*. But I want it to work on 3.7.6.

It works well on stand alone application but when put on web application it is causing problem.

I am using *Jboss*.

```
   13:12:37,078 WARN  [RequestProcessor] Unhandled Exception thrown: 
   class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException
   13:12:37,078 ERROR [[action]] Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
   java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 157: 
   vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA%20_WebApps/server/default/deploy/Myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/jasperreports-3.7.6.jar/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/docx/[Content_Types].xml
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.virtual.VFSUtils.toURI(VFSUtils.java:505)
at org.jboss.virtual.plugins.registry.DefaultVFSRegistry.getFile(DefaultVFSRegistry.java:140)
at org.jboss.virtual.protocol.AbstractVFSHandler.openConnection(AbstractVFSHandler.java:71)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadBytes(JRLoader.java:331)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadBytesFromLocation(JRLoader.java:474)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadBytesFromLocation(JRLoader.java:423)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.zip.FileBufferedZip.addEntry(FileBufferedZip.java:62)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.DocxZip.<init>(DocxZip.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter.exportReportToStream(JRDocxExporter.java:316)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRDocxExporter.exportReport(JRDocxExporter.java:230)
```

I tried encoding the paths. But it did not work even.

Please let me know if someone has solved this issue.

Comment: Are you talking about *JasperReports Server* or about custom application?

Comment: Its not in jasper server. Its normal custom application.